# How to update current activity from async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have listview in one screen and I will render this listview using customized arraylist(List).here when I want to refresh the listview from another java class I will refersh listview with context.But there is nomeaning if I will just refersh the listview ,I have to change the arraylist also.For this how can I change arraylist from another java class without using static modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Using the **reference (context)** of that activity update UI elements on `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask.

Comment: how can i populate listview with arraylist?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
...
private Activity context;

onCreate() {
   ...
   context = this;
   ...
   //run async task somewhere
}

class extends AsyncTask<> {

   onPostExecute() {
      AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog(context);
      // every time you used this on the activity you should use context on any other classes, including async task or other non activity classes
}
```

As mentioned by @Venkata Krishna comment below if you want to just update a property your code should like this:

```
...
private ArrayList<String> values;
private Activity context;

onCreate() {
    ...
    context = this;
    ...
    //run async task somewhere
}

class extends AsyncTask<> {
    private ArrayList<String> values;

    onPostExecute() {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog(context);
        //notice that there are 2 properties of values with the same name and the same signature
        //accessing async task's values
        this.values = ...;
        //accessing global parameter
        values = ...;
        // and then he would want to access the list adapter to update the infomation
        CustomListAdapter adapter = ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview)).getListAdapter();
        adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    }
}
```

Just java programming with global and inner class variables. For regular object you don't need to have the "context" of the activity. Just change the variables, if you want to access the UI you would need to do the trick with storing the context property.

Comment: When he wants to update Listview with arraylist he needs to update arraylist as well as listview.But your answer is good for only updating listview what about arraylist?

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you are trying to say but I guess this covers it. The context trick is used when you want to have access to UI functions or elements, in any other way you should just use the regular objective programming that is covered with pure Java